# python error can't open pdf in application from python

Tags: python-2.7, pdf

I am using windows 10 and python 2.7.13 .
My target is to open a pdf in acrobat reader at a specific page number.
I am using the code I received from one of the questions in the forum here.

```
import subprocess
import os

path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath('C:\test_file.pdf')
# I am testing this on my Windows Install machine
path_to_acrobat = os.path.abspath('C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe') 

# this will open your document on page 12
process = subprocess.Popen([path_to_acrobat, '/A', 'page=12', path_to_pdf], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
```

It opens up the acrobat reader application but the file doesnt open and i get the error :**"There was an error opening this document. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**

but when I use these commands in cmd without python I am successfully able to open the pdf without any error. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open the file with `r`:

```
path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath(r'C:\test_file.pdf')
path_to_acrobat = os.path.abspath(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe')
```

[Check this out too](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/28/on-spaces-in-the-paths-of-programs-and-files-on-windows), it will show to you an example of an error with the white spaces on the path

Answer (score 1):

Please check the path of your acrobat reader. 
In my case:

```
path_to_acrobat = os.path.abspath('C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\AcroRd32.exe')
```